# Show Cash on delivery (COD) based on specific cities in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, checkout

In Woocommerce I am showing Cash on delivery payment method only for a particular city using the following code:

```
function payment_gateway_disable_city( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city() == 'New York') {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } 
    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_city' );
```

It works fine. Now I need to handle multiple cities like Washington, San Francisco etc...

So I tried the following:

```
function payment_gateway_disable_city( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_city() == 'New York', 'San Fransisco' ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } 
    return $available_gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_disable_city' );
```

But it doesn't work… I get "WordPress experiencing technical difficulties".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

The following code will enable COD payments for specific defined cities.

You need to use an array of allowed cities with [`in_array()` PHP conditional function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'cities_based_payment_gateway_cod' );
function cities_based_payment_gateway_cod( $available_gateways ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return $available_gateways; // Only on frontend

    // HERE define the allowed cities in this array 
    $cities = array( 'New York', 'San Francisco' );

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && ! in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_city(), $cities ) ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } 
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted to know, after I integrate this code, only the cities i have mentioned will have COD! If other cities are selected, there wont be an option for the customer to select COD, am I right?

Comment: @Anas I have made a little change in the code. Yes you will have COD payment enabled only for **New York** and **San Francisco**... The cities are defined in an array in the function and you can add as many as you want.

Comment: this is what i was looking for, thanks alot, it works.